# Not distinct x values and different domain in one graph

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot data like this

```
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y     
     5 10
     6 12
     6 12
     7 11
}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y     
     5 8
     5 15
     6 10
     7 13
     8 14
}\dataB
```

The first problem is, that i don't have distinct x values,  6 in dataA and 5 in dataB. I thougt i could solve this with symbolic coords. But for this i have to change the x values...

The second problem is, that both data don't need to have the same domain, see the 8 in dataB.

What i want, is a graph starting with the smallest x value in my datas to the biggest. While doubled x values are marked with something. The graph should look like this:
[image]

I need a quick (and dirty if necessary) solution.
Thanks!
I generated the picture with this, note that the datas are modified!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y     
     5 10
     6 12
     6* 12
     7 11
}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y     
     5 8
     5* 15
     6 10
     7 13
     8 14
}\dataB
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scaled y ticks = false,
             symbolic x coords={5,5*,6,6*,7,8},
             xticklabels={5,6,7,8},
             xtick=data]    
 \addplot[mark=x,black] table[] from {\dataA};                            
 \addplot[mark=x,red] table[] from {\dataB};          
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which one would be the genuine one for say 5, do you have a preference?

Comment: The only 5 in dataA should match with the first 5 in dataB

Comment: What do you mean match? You mean they should be on `5` and everything else is starred? And so you have an order imposed and we can't sort the table.

Comment: Yes. But to remove any misunderstanding: I mean, that the value of 5 in dataA is 10. And the value of the first 5 in dataB is 8. Those two numbers should be over the same `x` namely above `5`. The second 5 in dataB is renamed to 5* and placed between the real 5 and 6. Just like in the picture. The sorting of the table has to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting `xtick=data` I think that you just need to write `xtick={5,5*,6,6*,7,8}` and to set the `xticklabels` to your specified set of labels (there should be a way to automate this using your data sets, but the manual suggests that there isn't...).

Doing this gives:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y
     5 10
     6 12
     6* 12
     7 11
}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread{
     x y
     5 8
     5* 15
     6 10
     7 13
     8 14
}\dataB
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scaled y ticks = false,
             symbolic x coords={5,5*,6,6*,7,8},
             xticklabels={5,5*,6,6*,7,8},
             xtick={5,5*,6,6*,7,8}]
             \addplot[mark=x,black,symbolc x coords={5,6,6*,7}] table[] from {\dataA};
 \addplot[mark=x,red] table[] from {\dataB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```